# Rails trying to strip html and white list, but sanitize not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sanitize, strip-tags

This is my current working code:

```
= auto_link(strip_tags(simple_format(truncate(user.notes, :length => 150, :separator => " ", :escape => false))),html: { target: '_blank' })
```

I'm using rich text editor, and I want to whitelist href or a tags, but the `sanitize` method doesn't work for me, only `strip_tags` removes the HTML tags that I want to.

How do I white list using `strip_tags`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) GEM.

For rich editor, I suggest sanitize when you save the content in to DB, not when you are going to display the content. It much more safe.

This is how I use in my project, in `before_save`, sanitize value.

```
safe_value = Sanitize.fragment(value,
                               :elements => %w{a b br em i li ol p strong u ul},
                               :attributes => {'a' => ['href'], 'p' => ['style'], 'ol' => ['style'], 'ul' => ['style'], 'li' => ['style']},
                               :add_attributes => {'a' => {'rel' => 'nofollow'}}, # nofollow for SEO
                               :protocols => {'a' => {'href' => ['http', 'https']}},
                               :css => {:properties => ['text-align', 'margin-left']})
```

Just adjust the options for your need.